# accordion broken with bootstrap 3 columns not working ... information re arranging into different columns

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, accordion, multiple-columns

I am using bootstrap 3.

My layout has two rows, the first with 2 columns, the second with 1.  When I expand the window to medium or large the title (listed as "Broken Title" on the jsfiddle) jumps up into the right column.  I cannot figure out why this is happening!

Also, the accordion only works in 12 col width.
The JSFiddle is in the comments.
http://jsfiddle.net/somedancetoforget/72qb7ere/7/

```
 <div style="margin-bottom:10px;  width:100%" class="col-md-12">

  <div class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg "><button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-warning btn-lg" style="margin-bottom:10px"><strong>+ New </strong></button></div>  
<div class=" col-sm-8 col-md-9 col-lg-8 col-xl-7" style="">
    <div class="panel-group widget" id="accordion" style="margin-top:0">
       <div class="panel panel-default ">
              <div class="panel-heading" >
                  <strong> PANEL TITLE </strong>
            </div>
            </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default ">

            <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle" style="border-bottom:1px #C1C1C1 solid">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" class="accordion-toggle" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne"style=" color:#666"><i class=" fa fa-check" ></i> Accordion #1 <span class=" badge badge-aqua">8</span> </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse ">
                <div class="panel-body">
                                  <ul>
                    <li> Name Name</li>
                                        <li> Name Name</li>

                    <li> Name Name</li>

                    <li> Name Name</li>

                    <li> Name Name</li>

                    <li> Name Name</li>

                    <li> Name Name</li>

</ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default ">
            <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle collapsed" style="border-bottom:1px #C1C1C1 solid">
                <h4 class="panel-title ">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" class="accordion-toggle" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" ><i class=" fa fa-question" ></i>Accordion #2 <span class=" badge badge-warning">55</span> </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse out">
                <div class="panel-body">


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default panel-participants-widget">
            <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" class="accordion-toggle" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" style="font-weight:300; color:#999;" > <i class=" fa fa-remove" ></i><em>Accordion 3</em> <span class=" badge badge-violet">2</span> </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                             <ul style="margin-bottom:-10px">
                    <li> Name Name</li>
                                        <li> Name Name</li>


</ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

            <div class="panel panel-default ">
              <div class="panel-heading" >


            </div>
            </div>
    </div>

</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-4 col-xl-5"  style=" height:100%">
    <div style="border: 1px #999 solid; background:#ececec; margin:0px 10px 20px 10px; padding:10px;" >
  <div class="hidden-xs" ><button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-warning btn-lg" style="margin-bottom:10px"><strong>+ New </strong></button></div>

    <div class="hidden-xs twitter-box" ><strong>Twitter</strong></div>
    </div>



</div>

</div>
<div class="col-md-12" ><div style="width:100%"> BROKEN TITLE<img  src="placeholder.png" width="940" height="90" style="background: #999;" ></img></div></div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/somedancetoforget/72qb7ere/7/

Comment: Please put your code into the question. From the help section: If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - but also include the code in your question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time.

Comment: I should put another live example in addition to the JSFiddle I originally put in my first coment, @Marcelo?

Comment: You should add the code from the original JSFiddle to your question (don't make a new comment). You can edit it, add the code, and near the top you will see a button to change that text into a code sample. Let me know if you need any help. In the future, also, try to use the least amount of code that still shows the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your layout is not designed using bootstrap's guidelines. You are not using bootstrap rows, but rather columns. This causes your floats not to be cleared correctly which is what creates the issue you are seeing.

Your elements should all be wrapped in a div with either the `container` or `container-fluid` bootstrap classes. Each row should be wrapped in a div with the `row` bootstrap class.

Additionally, there are quite a few other issues with your code, such as redundant/unnecessary CSS (Ex. a div with a `col-*-12` class already has 100% width).

Reduced HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid"> 
    <div style="margin-bottom:10px;" class="row">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="row"> 
        <div class="col-md-12"> 
            BROKEN TITLE<img  src="placeholder.png" width="940" height="90" style="background: #999;" ></img>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Live example with full code: http://jsfiddle.net/ay5Ld7qy/1/

Comment: Huge thank you.  You've just explained a lot and given me a lot to research.  Thanks!